# Meaning of "вот прям"

Tags: значения

I interpreted **вот прям** to mean *right now*, but I came across this sentence, where this wouldn't really make sense:

> Я тебя **вот прям** уважаю, но...

What is the meaning here?

Comment: another equivalent which is even semantically close is 'straight up' - man, i (just) respect you, straight up - the difference as you may have noticed is that the Russian phrase goes for interrogative sentences as well

Comment: Thank you, DK, the fact that it makes no sense here was the point of my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should most likely connect «*вот*» with «*я*», and «*прям*» with «*уважаю*». I think you should not connect «*вот*» and «*прям*» in one unit. "*Listen, I respect you so much, but…*”

“*Вот*" with “*я*” is often used to introduce some statement that is going to be new or unexpected: «*я вот тебе скажу …*», “*я вот думаю …*”, and so on. Such introduction might also mean that the statement is awkward, and I'm somewhat shy to say it.

«*Прям*» means that you shouldn't really think he doesn't respect you. The closest explanation is “*plain*”: my respect is something plain, there is readily that and that to say about my respect, so don't be mistaken thinking I don't respect you; better listen to what I say.

An example: «*Я прямо не знаю …*» — “*Really, I don't know …*” One might also translate: «*я тебя прям уважаю, но*» — “*I really respect you, but…*”

Comment: Hey, what's the problem? The statement is true, the examples are telling, the exposition is clear, the translation is adequate. I think all that requires an exact statement of the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I just saw your response, but it's very helpful indeed. I especially like your perspective on the use of вот as a personal "introduction" to what the speaker may find awkward to say outright. Good stuff!

Comment: You only got my vote, but I liked your answer the most because it went below the surface and told me what I wanted to know)))

Answer (score 10):

*Прям(о)* is a parasite word colloquially used to emphasize something. It could correspond to any of *just*, *really*, *exactly* or whichever you use for this task.

A pair of examples,

> Я тебя прям зауважал --> You really earned my respect
>   Я прям не знаю что сказать --> I just don't know what to say
>   Это прям то что надо --> That's exactly what I/you/we/etc. need

"*Вот прям*" is a widespread pleonasm, as both words mean the same. Sort of "*just really*", I guess.

Comment: Thank you, Matt. So in a way it's like the colloquial counterpart of как раз in these examples?

Comment: @CocoPop "Как раз" is tricky. In (1) and (2) anyone could understand it as "by the way": "я как раз не знаю что сказать" --> "By the way, I don't know what to say". Or alternatively, if you do stress "Я" it becomes: "And for my part, I don't know what to say".

Comment: JUST REALLY is actually very expressive and common in English. Great analogy)))

Answer (score 9):

вот прям has nothing to do with time. The closest translation will be "really", though it may wary depending on context

Examples:

вот прям щас – "right now". Note that it's usually used with "щас" instead of "сейчас", which is not a correct word, but imitation of how it sounds.

Я тебя вот прям уважаю — I do really respect you.

— показал охраннику паспорт моего друга и прошел — что, вот прям так и прошел?

— showed the guard my friend's document and walked in. – Really? Walked in, just like that?

Comment: or to emphasize - just really